# Share session between multiple applications using .net core

Tags: .net-core, sql-session-state

We are using SQL Session state to persist data in legacy application and access in future application application.

If anyone has idea how to share the SQL session state between multiple sites using .net core then please share the info.

Step 1: We have legacy application where we need to login and redirect to future migrated application.

Step 2: When redirection happen to future application session needs to be persisted and to be accessible in future application

If anybody worked on above scenario under .NET Core, please share the information.